# Why is NPoco ignoring column and property names and mapping almost randomly?

Tags: c#, petapoco, micro-orm, npoco

I'm using the NPoco ORM (a branch of PetaPoco) but I've just noticed it's mapping the columns incorrectly in some cases.

I'm using a stored procedure and my POCO property names are identical to the column names produced by the stored procedure:

```
string sql = "EXEC API_GetVenueSummaryByID @@venueID = @venueID";
var venue = db.FirstOrDefault<VenueSummary>(sql, new { venueID = venueID });
```

The stored procedure is a simple SELECT statement with a couple of variables included (removing them doesn't help):

```
DECLARE @hasOffers bit
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Offers WHERE dbo.Offers.EntryType='V' AND Offers.EntryID =   @VenueID AND GETDATE() <= validToDate) SET @hasOffers = 1

SELECT  
    Venue.VenueID, VenueName, Town, County, Country, PackageCode,       
    MeetingRoomsNo, MaxMeetingCapacity, BedroomsNo,
    MetaDescription AS ShortDescription,
    'dummyresult.jpg' AS PrimaryImageFilename,
    @hasOffers AS HasSpecialOffers,
    CAST(TimeStamp AS BIGINT) AS RecordVersion
FROM dbo.Venue
WHERE Venue.VenueID = @VenueID
```

Is there a function in NPoco which causes it to guess the mappings (ignoring their names)? If so, how I can I disable this and force it to only match based on the column and property names?

<strike>Currently the only work around seems to be to use the column attribute</strike> ***<-- doesn't work either***

At the moment, even someone auto-formatting stored procedure (or any change which results in a change of column order) is breaking the application.

**Edit 2**

I've noticed that if I restart the website application (eg by editing web.config or updating application code) then the column order fixes itself. So I can only assume the problem is related to NPoco internally caching the column indexes - and if the indexes change, the mappings will then be incorrect. I'm not sure if there's a mechanism to clear the cache that's perhaps not working?

Comment: Show us `API_GetVenueSummaryByID`.

Comment: @BCdotNET Updated to include the stored procedure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NPoco, but I did notice they have some [examples for using stored procedures](https://gist.github.com/litera/11205851). Plus there is [NPoco.StoredProcedures](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPoco.StoredProcedures/). Have you tried any of these?

Comment: What do you mean by `mapping the columns incorrectly in some cases`? If the columns returned from the SP have the same names as the property names of `VenueSummary`, there is no need to use the column attributes on the property names.

Comment: @CallMeKags But that's exactly what I have to do in order to get it to map correctly, or it will map the columns almost randomly. You're right in that it shouldn't be needed - hence me posting this question.

Comment: @NickG What version of NPoco are you using?

Comment: NPoco 2.5.77 from nuget

Comment: The problem still exists in the 2.5.82-beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with how NPoco (and PetaPoco) caches the codegen that is used to map from a SQL statement to a POCO.

Usually this isn't a problem if you are changing the code when you are changing the SQL as the cache will be rebuild, however if you create your POCO first then start to change the SP after the first initial run the mappings will be incorrect.

This issues has now been fixed in 2.5.83-beta, and it will now look at the column names and their positions to determine the cache key.

Thanks for the help @NickG